# Annoying password system dilemma. (Localized system)

Tags: security, passwords, system, reset

So I have this little configuration tool set up, where a user must enter a password in order to edit a file which is otherwise encrypted on the computer. It's decently secure, though anyone who really wants to get access could probably do so. Now, the boss says to add in a password changing mechanism (no doubt to chance the password to something like 1234 that he can spread around to anyone). Simple, right?

The problem is, what happens when no one knows the password or the password file is deleted? (Yes I am storing hashes) Do I just let them make a new password? If so, what is stopping an unauthorized user from just deleting the password file and trivially gaining access to the program? Resetting it to a default pass is hardly any better. But the thought of leaving people with a system that is completely unusable because they forgot the password is somewhat unsettling. And since it's all client-side I have no way to support an authorized reset.; I'm an amateur here and have no idea what to do, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to distinguish between an attacker and someone who has forgotten their password/PIN. The use of security questions is debatable, but without a way to obtain the current password, it's of little help anyway. Some allow a password reminder (hint).

It's normal to deny access to local encrypted data if the user has lost their password/PIN.

If you forget the PIN to unlock your iPad, you can reset your iPad, but you will lose any local data that isn't saved elsewhere.

Microsoft does the same thing. If you change the password on your account without entering the previous password, you will lose access to any encrypted files.

Let them reset the password, but they'll lose access to any encrypted files.

Comment: +1. This is pretty much the only secure option in this case. Storing the password (or anything that makes it easy to guess the password) along with the encrypted content is not a good idea.

Comment: Sounds good. But in my case I absolutely CANNOT have someone unauthorized changing things - in this case, resetting the configuration and adding their own. The data isn't really secret, it's just not supposed to be editable without authorization. I think I will go with the denying access, thank you.